# How do we convert the augmented yang files to python classes using pyang or any other python library

Tags: python, ietf-netconf

I have few yang files on the device which include the ietf defined interface yang file (ietf-interfaces.yang) and vendor specific augmented yang file (eci-interfaces-aug.yang)
When i use pyang to generate python classes for augmented yang file which imports the ietf-interface yang file i see the python file with eci-interfaces-aug class but it doesn't have any definitions inside or any variables to access.

Can anyone please advise me how to convert the augmented/deviated yang files to python classes in order to generate xml for netconf operations